# can anyone please explain to me why i get this bug and how i can solve it? Saving Prefab to immutable folder is not allowed

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm making an AR app for my thesis project using unity and vuforia. My project works perfectly on the web but when I want to build I get this bug that I don't know how to fix. Can anyone please explain to me why do i get this error and how i can fix it?

I have tried installing Vuforia in a new project and starting over to see if the bug would disappear but it was again there in the new project.

*Saving Prefab to immutable folder is not allowed: Packages/com.ptc.vuforia.engine/Vuforia/Prefabs/DefaultPlaneIndicator.prefab
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()*

Comment: [IMMUTABLE PACKAGE ERRORS ARE THROWN WHEN SELECTING A PREFAB CONTAINING CANVAS COMPONENT](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/core-render-pipeline-argumentexception-cant-save-an-immutable-prefab)  (shouting caps not mine).

Comment: Also, [this one](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/saving-prefab-to-immutable-folder-is-not-allowed-error-is-thrown-when-saving-a-prefab-with-an-xrinteractorlinevisual-component).

Comment: and [this one](https://forum.unity.com/threads/cant-create-the-default-script-references.1131361/).